# R/Mongolite: How to $unwind a dataframe?

Tags: r, aggregate, pipeline, mongolite

I am using mongolite. I have an array in my dataset, which I would like to deconstruct using $unwind. I did the following:

```
pUsers <- pUsers$aggregate(pipeline = {"$unwind" : "$profile.hobbies"})
```

The result:

```
Error in "$unwind":"$profile.hobbies" : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In inherits(x, "bson") : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In inherits(x, "bson") : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Seeing the error message, I tried to exclude data with NA value, with the following code:

```
pUsers <- pUsers$aggregate(pipeline = '[
        {"$match" : {"$profile.hobbies" : {"$exists" : true}}}, 
        {"$unwind" : "$profile.hobbies"}]')
```

Result:

```
Error: unknown top level operator: $profile.hobbies
```

Can someone explain the error I made? Moreover, how can I correctly unwind my dataframe?
Thank you!

Comment: Try quoting entire expression as R does not use curly braces and colons in its syntax like that: `pUsers$aggregate(pipeline = '{"$unwind" : "$profile.hobbies"}')`

Comment: hi! I have tried writing it as a string (what you say here), yet this is the result:


       `bson_append_array(): invalid array detected. first element of array 
       parameter is not "0".
       Error: Each element of the 'pipeline' array must be an object`

Comment: Try placing the call in brackets: `pUsers$aggregate(pipeline = '[{"$unwind" : "$profile.hobbies"}]')` as [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) show.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, R's syntax does not conform to Mongo's query calls, specifically with curly braces and colons unlike other languages that can support these symbols in those positions.

Therefore, be sure to wrap entire calls in quoted strings with all needed symbols such as square brackets. Specifically the following:

```
pUsers <- pUsers$aggregate(pipeline = {"$unwind" : "$profile.hobbies"})
```

Should be modified as

```
pUsers <- pUsers$aggregate(pipeline = '[{"$unwind" : "$profile.hobbies"}]')
```